# Flutter ToDo list checkbox cant assign bool

Tags: flutter, dart, assign

Im trying to develop a ToDo list with flutter.

Im running a Stateful Widget for the list, the build method for its state looks like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('ToDo App'),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(35, 0, 0, 100),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: products.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            String key = products.keys.elementAt(index);
            return ToDoListEntry(
                key, products[key], () => deleteItem(key), () => check(key));
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: newEntry,
        child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

a function addItem(String item) is working, also a function deleteItem(String key), i pass to the ToDoListEntry class is working.
Now i tried to code updating functionality for the Checkbox and saved my entries into the Map<String, bool> products:

```
Map<String, bool> products = {
    'Kartoffel': false,
    'Tomate': false,
    'Käse': false,
    'Wurst': false
  };
```

When i now passed products[key] to my ToDoListEntry Widget it says: "The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'"

What is 'bool?' i cant find any explainations.

ToDoListEmtry looks like this:

```
class ToDoListEntry extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  bool state;
  final Function remove, check;
  ToDoListEntry(this.title, this.state, this.remove, this.check);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
      child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        leading: Checkbox(
          value: state,
          onChanged: (bool value) => check(),
        ),
        title: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black54),
        ),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
          onPressed: () => remove(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here i get problems with the onChecked method in Checkbox: "The argument type 'void Function(bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void'"

Comment: You can make this Null Safe by adding  `onChanged: (bool? value) => check(),`.

Comment: I already tried that, changed a list of bools to 'bool?', but then the function didnt work. I need to somehow figure out, how 'bool?' works.

Comment: The thing is `bool?` means  means literally `bool or null`. Whereas `bool` means `bool and nothing else`. Calling  `someMap[someKey]` returns `bool?` because there maybe no element at that index. If you're sure it exists, use bang operator (`!`). You need to read about null safety first anyway I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to the map entry `products[key]` must be trailed by the ! operator, to guarantee that it won't be null.

```
return ToDoListEntry(
  key, products[key]!, () => deleteItem(key), () => check(key));
}),
```

The `onChanged` method for my Checkbox must be `nullsafe` for some reason. The error doesn't point that out.

```
leading: Checkbox(
          value: state,
          onChanged: (bool? value) => check(),
        ),
```